# Speed up replacing images

Tags: android, multithreading, android-image

I need to change images in ImageSwitcher (or any other widget which is preferable) every 200ms. I tried to use AsyncTask and update image source in `onProgressUpdate()` method. I tried also `runOnUiThread()` but both ways are pretty slow. How Can I show images faster? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Gallery has around 15-20 images. Size of each image is between 150-200kb - resolution 1080x1920. ImageSwitcher

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);

                imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) view.findViewById(R.id.is_loginSwitcher);


                imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
                    @Override
                    public View makeView() {
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

                        return imageView;
                    }
                });
                return view;
    }

        private class SwitchImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... values) {
                    int position = 0;
                    while (position < gallery.length - 1) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        publishProgress(position);
                        position++;
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(gallery[values[0]]);
                }
            }
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/is_loginSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could try using a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and updating the images in onDraw.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried so we can get a complete picture of what you're trying to achieve and give us details of how many pictures you're trying to switch between, sizes of images, etc. so we can make relevant suggestions.

Comment: @HexAndBugs I updated my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps good idea would be to consider using libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of plain ImageView. These libraries would **cache scaled down** version of your source images, so next time you would be going to show them, it definitely would need less time to read and decode the bitmap, giving you speed boost you are looking for.